# How to detect border-radius with percentage value browser support?

Tags: css, cross-browser

In order to draw with CSS3 using the box-shadow property combined with a border-radius:50% (to make circles), I would like to detect if the browser supports or not this percentage value for border-radius.
For example, Safari 5.1+ only supports it.

Is there a way to detect this or do I have to check the browser name and its version. The drawback for this second solution is of course that I have to know and  list all the browsers and versions that pose problems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**Modernizr** JS library](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css) to detect this feature; it'll detect support of CSS3 `border-radius` (among many many other things) and add a class `.borderradius` in browsers that do support it (and have JS activated, obviously)

If you don't want to load this resource, you can look at the source code on GitHub.

EDIT: better yet, you can [custom build Modernizr to only test for this property](http://modernizr.com/download/#-borderradius-testprop-testallprops-domprefixes) and it'll give you a 2kB uncompressed script.
By checking *Don't minify source* below the custom code, you'll have a way smaller code to read, if that's your intent.

Comment: I already use Modernizr but what I want to do is to check support of the border-radius property with a percentage value. Modernizr will set the borderradius class even if a percentage value is not supported.